# Which tool should I use figure out the function call sequence of an ARM binary (both windows and linux)?

Tags: debugging, arm

I have a bare metal ARM binary. I would like to know which function does it call in the source code because I do not know how the source code is compiled. I would like to know tools that I can use to figure these out (It can be linux only or windows only tool, but I want to know options for both platforms.)

Comment: Depends if it's a bare-metal binary (in which case you can't do much except disassemble it), or an ELF image (in which case there are tools like readelf/objdump) or something else... There really isn't enough information in the question, and as it stands it looks a lot like an off-topic "please recommend me a tool..."

Comment: I updated it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Google ['ARM decompiler'](https://www.google.ca/#q=arm+decompiler).  Also check stack-overflow [tag:decompiler] and the questions there.  You can also use the Gnu binutil's *objdump* and get an assembler listing.  If it is 'C', then 90% are usually called with `bl` or `blx` as a function call.  You can accumulate the addresses from these instructions/call sights and make a graph.  If it is C++, or C with extensive use of function pointers, then it maybe more difficult (even with a decompiler).